# why dose nodes names become a,b,c when I already gave them a name to be set?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with real time database , when I was testing the app as debug every thing was fine nodes name was right , when I lunched it to google play and download it to test , I found that nodes name is sit as a b c d ,I tried adding @PropertyName on gutters and sitters but didn't work . what I am missing ?

Comment: That typically means you didn't configure proguard. I linked some questions where this was covered before.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks man rely appreciate it